# CSS Menu children forcing parents to resize

Tags: html, css

I am currently using the following code:

**HTML**

```
<div id="wrap">
  <ul class="navbar">
    <li><a href="#">COMPARE PLANS</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">BENEFITS</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">LARGE CORPORATES</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">SMALL & MEDIUM<br> BUSINESSES</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">ENTREPRENEURS &<br> START-UPS</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">EDUCATION &<br> NON-PROFIT</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">WEB DEVELOPERS &<br> AGENCIES</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">ARTISTS &<br> CELEBRITIES</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">GET STARTED</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">.NET</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">PHP</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">FACEBOOK</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

And **CSS**

```
#wrap {
    width: 100%;
    height: 16px;
    margin: 0;
    z-index: 99;
    position: relative;
    color:#2C2C2C;
}
.navbar {
    height: 16px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    float:right;
    margin-top:20px;
}
.navbar > li {
    height: auto;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
    list-style: none;
    font: 12px Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    padding: 0;
    margin-left:17px;
}
.navbar a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
    display: block;
}
.navbar > li:hover {
    color: #6D4B78;
}
.navbar > a:hover {
    color: #6D4B78;
}
.navbar li ul {
    display: none;
    height: auto;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background: url("header_bg.jpg") repeat-x scroll 0 0 #FFFFFF;
    border: 1px solid #E0E0E0;
}
.navbar li:hover ul {
    display: block;
}
.navbar li ul li {
    min-height:12px;
    padding: 8px 5px;
}
.navbar > li > ul > li:hover {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #664670;
    color:#FFFFF;
}
```

My problem is this:

When I hover on *Benefits*, the element is re-sizing. Essentially, it is growing to match the width of its child elements (the `LI`s in the drop-down) which are larger than it.

I want the *Benefits* element to be fixed-width, and I haven't allotted any sizing to the `UL` elements.

To clarify, I would like my overflow to look like this:

[image]

Currently, though, when not hovering, I get this:

[image]

And when hovering, I get this:

[image]

What do I need to do to fix it?

Comment: I used Pure CSS for this. can any one tell me how to stop my Benefits element expanding when i hover thank you

Comment: the dropdown needs to be absolutely positioned so your container will not expand

Comment: but I have 7 lists like that i have to position all of them. I want something other than position absolute

Comment: You set everything in the css to left: 0 or right: 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this, very basic dropdown menu. You can set left or right to 0 or whatever you are comfortable with. If your menu is on the right side of the screen, then setting right 0 would probably be better

http://jsfiddle.net/k4Jcq/2/

```
.navbar li {
  position: relative;     
}
.navbar li ul   
{
  display: none;
  height: auto;                                   
  margin: 0; 
  padding: 0;
  background: url("header_bg.jpg") repeat-x scroll 0 0 #FFFFFF;
  border: 1px solid #E0E0E0;  
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
}
```

Comment: I have some other problem can you tell me

Comment: Post a different question if it is not related to this

Comment: @SaiPhani ask a new question about the particulars of what you need to do. Also specify if javascript/jquery can be used in the new question

Comment: @SaiPhani post as new question

Comment: posted here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16347159/css-popup-on-top-of-element-when-hover/16347254?noredirect=1#16347254

Answer (score 0):

I had this very same problem. The key is to absolute the menu and then place it where you want. http://jsfiddle.net/cornelas/k4Jcq/embedded/result/

```
.navbar li ul   
 {
 display: none;
 height: auto;                                   
 margin: 0; 
 padding: 0;
 background: url("header_bg.jpg") repeat-x scroll 0 0 #FFFFFF;
 border: 1px solid #E0E0E0;  
 position: absolute;
 right: 70px;
 }
```

Comment: But get started dropdown is also getting under benifits

Comment: container of the dropdown needs to be relative